# Embedded: SDHC SPI write issue

Tags: embedded, block, msp430, spi

I am currently working at a logger that uses a MSP430F2618 MCU and SanDisk 4GB SDHC Card.

Card initialization works as expected, I also can read MBR and FAT table.

The problem is that I can't write any data on it. I have checked if it is write protected by notch, but it's not. Windows 7 OS has no problem reading/writing to it.

Though, I have used a tool called "HxD" and I've tried to alter some sectors (under Windows). When I try to save the content to SD card, the tool pop up a windows telling me "Access denied!".

Then I came back to my code for writing to SD card:

```
uint8_t SdWriteBlock(uchar_t *blockData, const uint32_t address)
{
    uint8_t result = OP_ERROR;
    uint16_t count;
    uchar_t dataResp;
    uint8_t idx;

    for (idx = RWTIMEOUT; idx > 0; idx--)
    {
        CS_LOW();
        SdCommand(CMD24, address, 0xFF);

        dataResp = SdResponse();

        if (dataResp == 0x00)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            CS_HIGH();
            SdWrite(0xFF);
        }
    }

    if (0x00 == dataResp)
    {
        //send command success, now send data starting with DATA TOKEN = 0xFE
        SdWrite(0xFE);
        //send 512 bytes of data
        for (count = 0; count < 512; count++)
        {
            SdWrite(*blockData++);
        }
        //now send tow CRC bytes ,through it is not used in the spi mode
        //but it is still needed in transfer format
        SdWrite(0xFF);
        SdWrite(0xFF);
        //now read in the DATA RESPONSE TOKEN
        do
        {
            SdWrite(0xFF);
            dataResp = SdRead();
        }
        while (dataResp == 0x00);
        //following the DATA RESPONSE TOKEN are a number of BUSY bytes
        //a zero byte indicates the SD/MMC is busy programing, 
        //a non_zero byte indicates SD/MMC is not busy
        dataResp = dataResp & 0x0F;
        if (0x05 == dataResp)
        {
            idx = RWTIMEOUT;
            do
            {
                SdWrite(0xFF);
                dataResp = SdRead();
                if (0x0 == dataResp)
                {
                    result = OP_OK;
                    break;
                }
                idx--;
            }
            while (idx != 0);

            CS_HIGH();
            SdWrite(0xFF);
        }
        else
        {
            CS_HIGH();
            SdWrite(0xFF);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem seems to be when I am waiting for card status:

```
do
{
    SdWrite(0xFF);
    dataResp = SdRead();
}
while (dataResp == 0x00);
```

Here I am waiting for a response of type "X5"(hex value) where X is undefined.

But most of the cases the response is 0x00 (hex value) and I don't get out of the loop. Few cases are when the response is 0xFF (hex value).

I can't figure out what is the problem.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: (You are using magic numbers in your code and in your question, which makes it really hard to understand.) I couldn't find anywhere on the SD card protocol specification that says that no CRC is used on WRITE and READ data transfer, the document only claims that CRC is not used on commands. CRC faults makes the card to not respond.

Comment: Read the spec again, CRC is disabled once the card enters SPI mode.

Comment: Maybe you should read the spec again @TurboJ. `In the CRC OFF mode, the CRC bits of the COMMAND are defined as 'don't care' for the transmitter and ignored by the receiver.
The SPI interface is initialized in the CRC OFF mode in default.` There text is clear when it says that CRC is disabled to COMMAND. There is more: `A valid data block is suffixed with a 16-bit CRC generated by the standard CCITT polynomial x16+x12+x5+1.`

Comment: Read chapter 7.2.2 *carefully*. The intention is to leave out all CRC checking completely. Leaving out only the CRC-7 makes no sense when you have to apply the much more complex CRC-16 to the data. My working codebase proves this - I do not use any CRC there.

Answer (score 0):

> 4GB SDHC

We need to see *much* more of your code. Many µC SPI codebases only support SD cards <= 2 GB, so using a smaller card might work.

You might check it yourself: SDHC needs a CMD 8 and an ACMD 41 after the CMD 0 (GO_IDLE_STATE) command, otherwise you cannot read or write data to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, but I solved my problem. It was a problem of timing. I had to put a delay at specific points.